# Почему статическая переменная, содержащая символ не меняется при ее инкрементировании?

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     $number = 5;
     echo "Глобальное число: $number<br>";
     function show_local() {
         $number = 100;
         echo "Локальное число: $number<br>";
     }
     show_local();

     function recursion() {
         global $number;
         static $letter = 'А';

         if ($number < 14) {
             echo "$number:$letter | ";
             $number++; $letter++; recursion();
         }
     }
     recursion();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Переменная $letter инкрементируется в функции рекурсивной функции recursion() раз за разом, но не меняет свое значение. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: исправьте на английскую `А`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему так

Как ни странно, ответ на вопрос вы можете найти в [документации к оператору `++`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.increment.php)

> PHP следует соглашениям Perl (в отличие от С) касательно выполнения арифметических операций с символьными переменными. Например, в PHP и Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; присвоит $a значение 'AA', в то время как в C a = 'Z'; a++; присвоит a значение '[' (ASCII-значение 'Z' равно 90, а ASCII-значение '[' равно 91). Следует учесть, что к символьным переменным можно применять операцию инкремента, в то время как операцию декремента применять нельзя, кроме того, **поддерживаются только ASCII-символы (a-z и A-Z). Попытка инкремента/декремента других символьных переменных не будет иметь никакого эффекта, исходная строка останется неизменной.**

-

> как это исправить?

Как следует из документации, поддерживаются только ASCII-символы, в вашем же случае в тексте стоит русская буква `А`. Заменив ее на английскую, вы сможете добиться желаемого поведения. Если же вы хотели инкрементировать русский алфавит, то придется использовать другие методы (с получением кода буквы).

*зы: вообще не знал, что их можно так инкрементировать :D*

Comment: Спасибо) Но все же не понимаю как инкрементировать русский алфавит другими методами

Comment: Я попробовал сделать так: $letter = chr(ord($letter)+1);

Comment: Но вместо русских символов выводит знаки вопроса