# Обнуление ассоциативного массива с буквами кириллического алфавита в качестве ключей

Tags: php

Пишу класс для игры в города на PHP. Скрипт должен выступать в качестве ведущего. Соответственно, определять, на какую букву нужно называть следующий город. Так как на некоторые буквы городов мало, а на некоторые, напротив, много, решил сделать ассоциативный массив, хранящий в себе количество еще не названных городов на все буквы алфавита, чтобы предотвратить ситуации, когда продолжить игру будет нельзя по причине того, что городов на определенную букву больше не осталось.

Я столкнулся с проблемой того, что такой вот код не работает:

```php
 for ($i='а'; $i<='я'; $i++)
            $this->namedletters[$i]=0;
```

Вопрос, собственно, в следующем: как обнулить такой массив наименее костыльным путем?

Comment: а зачем его обнулять в логике данной игры? согласно алгоритму его разве что можно заполнить исходными значениями, и в процессе игры постепенно уменьшать значения. или нет?

Comment: емнип, согласно документации инкрементация символов доступна лишь для английского алфавита, поэтому в данном случае `$i++` не работает. [не так давно обсуждалось что-то подобное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975992/223826)

Comment: Получается вы храните в массиве `$this->namedletters = ['а' => ['Астрахань', 'Архангельск']]` и т.д. ?

Comment: @teran, чтобы инкрементировать. Дальше я пишу счетчик типа
`foreach ($this->lines as $city) { $this->namedletters[mb_strtolower(mb_substr($city, 0, 1, 'UTF-8'))]++; }`
Который заполняет массив, где записано количество городов, оставшихся на каждую букву.

Comment: @Mully, не, я там просто количество держу.

Comment: `array_map()` не подойдет?

Comment: А как написать callback-функцию, которая отдает буквы кириллического алфавита по порядку? На ум приходит разве что захардкоженый массив с алфавитом. Других вариантов нет?

Comment: не понимаю, если вы храните количество *оставшихся* городов, то надо уменьшать, казалось бы, а не увеличивать счетчики?

Comment: можете разве что взять строку с алфавитом, и разбить ее на буквы программно.

Comment: Копайте в сторону ASCII таблицы методы конвертации русских букв, потом инкрементируйте счётчик в цикле. Либо хардкодить - что лучше, потому что 33 буквы всего и потом форичем, или array_map()

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($this->namedletters as &$value){
    $value = 0;
}
```

Comment: Но ведь изначально же в массиве нет ключей с буквами кириллического алфавита...

Comment: Ааа. Тогда, может такой вариант `$keys = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', ..., 'ю', 'я']; foreach ($this->keys as $key){ $this->namedletters[$key] = 0; }`?

Comment: Ну похоже да, самый нормальный вариант получается таким вот костылем не оч красивым. Просто не очень хотелось так поступать, но, видимо, нет вариантов... Спасибо тогда :)